# Add new record button edits existing record

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database

I'm trying to pull in the last record from each in a list of devices, alter those records and save them as new records via a form. The idea is to make a daily log of their statuses and since most will change little if at all this approach seemed the most efficient way to do that. I've written the following query and used it to design a form:

```
SELECT 
    ns.gateway, 
    n.[node serial number], 
    ns.online, 
    ns.[not in service],
    ns.[location status], 
    ns.[install/remove],
    ns.notes
FROM 
    [node status] AS ns 
    INNER JOIN nodes AS n ON ns.[node serial] = n.nodeid
WHERE 
    (((ns.[date verified])=(SELECT MAX(ns2.[date verified]) FROM [node status] AS ns2 WHERE ns2.[node serial]=ns.[node serial])) AND 
    ((ns.decomissioned)>=0) AND 
    ((ns.[not in service])>=0))
ORDER BY 
    ns.gateway
```

[image]

Up until this point it works great. The issue is that when I click the "Add Records" button you see above it edits the last record rather than creating a new one. I did set the button to create a new record. Here is the macro for that:

[image]

I put the button in the footer, so I don't know if that might be part of the issue, but I wanted it to apply to all records with one button rather than having an individual button for each. It does apply to all records, but like I said it edits rather than creates new records. I also tried changing the form's `Data Entry` property to `Yes`, but then the form stops pulling in the last records. So what you see above is when this property is set to `No`.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

***Update***

I am attempting to replicate this with an unbound form. I'm trying to pull in the information that has been filtered by the query above, and it does bring in the first record but it just duplicates it on subsequent lines.

So I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how to use a multiple items form that is unbound and/or am I even on the right track.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [node audit query]")

    Gateway.Value = rst!Gateway
    node_serial.Value = rst![Node Serial Number]
    Online.Value = rst!Online
    Not_in_Service.Value = rst![Not In Service]
    location.Value = rst![Location Status]
    Install_Remove.Value = rst![Install/Remove]
    Notes.Value = rst![Notes]

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a bound form here. If you edit the data, you edit the existing records. You will have to: either **copy** the records and then show them for editing, or use an unbound form (or bound to a temp table, if you want a continuous form).

Comment: Thanks @Andre, I'll look into both those approaches.

Comment: @taffyhound As Andre noted, a  continuous form (multiple records displayed) has to be bound to a recordset (e.g. temp table).How do you retrive the status data? Can't there be multiple changes (e.g. on/off/on) the same day? What about a seperate data-entry form? Just display the last status, as you did on start, but to add a status change, open the entry form (unbound, single form, popup) on double click, populate the controls with selected record and save after edit(s).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a temp table and using a bound form ended up being the best solution. Thank you to both Andre and ComputerVersteher for the advice.